# Polymer 1.0 components in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer, web-component

How to use Polymer 1.0 components in Polymer 2 project
some of the good components are available in polymer 1.0 but not in polymer 2.0 as I am developing my project in Polymer 2.0 so need components of polymer 2.

Comment: Why would you want to do that. There are good enough components in Polymer 2

Answer (score 2):

Polymer 2 was officially out, and it is said that you can use full Polymer 1.x in your 2.x builds.

Comment: It'd be painful when you're using a component built for Polymer 1.x, and its owner is not active, and has no timeline to embrace Polymer 2. You might be locked in hybrid mode forever, or abandon the obsolete components.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is a compatibility version layer between the one and the two, too be able to use old polymer 1 components.

Since polymer 2 is not officially out, I'm not sure this layer is totally finished, but there is some info here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#polymer-1-compatibility-layer

There is also a video on the Migration process to 2.0 here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI3G-tzbC_Q